# PostCSS & Webpack configuration

Tags: css, webpack, webpack-2, postcss, cssnext

I'm really disheartened, because I can't find any useful resource on the subject.

I merely want to watch my .css files, use post css' plugins to transform them and finally export them to my /public folder as I already do with my .jsx files

Here's my web pack configuration

```
    const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve('src/index.jsx'),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('public'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    devServer: {
        publicPath: "/",
        contentBase: "./public"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader',
                            options: {
                                modules: true,
                                localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
                            }
                        }, {
                            loader: 'postcss-loader',
                            options: {
                                plugins: function() {
                                    return [require('lost'), require('postcss-cssnext'), require('postcss-import')]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                })
            }, {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                        }
                    }
                ],
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [new ExtractTextPlugin("main.css")]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are using webpack2

If you want your css file dumped out separately, you would need ExtractTextPlugin. Here is my css loader which works

I define the post css plugins right within the webpack config, because then it stays in one place. Hope this helps:

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
...
...
module.exports = {
...
...
    module: {
        rules: [
...
...
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
                    { fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: [{
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            modules: true,
                            localIdentName:'[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: {
                            plugins: function() {
                                return [
                                    require('autoprefixer')
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                ]
            })
        },
}
```

Comment: Updated my code. Runs without errors but there is no output.

Comment: are you importing css files inside your js? something like : import styles from './styles/buttons.css';

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your plugins are incorrectly created.

Try

```
return [require('lost')(), require('postcss-cssnext')(), require('postcss-import')()]
```

(Note the () to invoke the plugin creation).

Also are you actually using import/require() to include your css? If not you should, no magic stuff will glob your css :)

Comment: Btw, postcss-import should be the first plugin of your list.